# Symfony2 Form handler check changes before persist

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'd like to check changes of my hydrated entity before the persist.

I've tryed to get a new entity into the onSuccess (after bindRequest) with DB values using a find, but this object have the hydrated values instead of DB values !

This is what i've tryed :

```
public function onSuccess(TachesDetails $detail) {
    $tache_new = $detail->getTache();
    $tache_old = $this->em->getRepository('NomDuBundle:Taches')->find($tache_new->getId());
    var_dump($tache_old);
    // ...
    $this->em->persist($detail);
    $this->em->persist($detail->getTache());
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

Var_dump of $tache_old give me hydrated values.

**EDIT :**

I've find the solution after hours.

To resolve this problem, you'll have to create a clone of your entity in the controller and send it trough formHandler parameters.

In the onSuccess function, you can access it like this :

```
$this->entityCloned
```

Comment: You should better answer your own question and then accept it instead of posting the solution inside your question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you could use [`prePersist` event](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/events.html#prepersist) for checking what changed. It's more suitable than `onSuccess`.

There's also more native way to check changes, using [`UnitOfWork` object](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/working-with-objects.html):

```
$unitOfWork = $entityManager->getUnitOfWork();
$unitOfWork->computeChangeSets();
$changes = $unitOfWork->getEntityChangeSet($yourEntity);
```